# Cannot delete parent entity because child reference in bidirectional mapping case

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

As I mentioned in title I'm having trouble when I try to remove a "parent" entity due its children references due a data integrity violation. I supposed the error is related to some missing configuration of the entities, but I cannot get what is missing.
Is it possible to let understand to Hibernate/JPA to delete the children reference before and then the parent? I would like to keep using this relation and the Spring Data JPA repositories.

If it's possibile by JPA/Hibernate, I would like to avoid to handle these cases by using explicitly the entity manager (so I do not want to delete them "manually"), because Spring JPA by the auto-query generation is helping a lot with a huge boost to all the 'select/count/..' cases.

Parent-Child relationship is mapped in both side, where:

1. parent does not own a colum so the mapping is configured by "mappedBy"
2. child has a composite key where one of the columns is linked to the parent by its id
3. configuration is made by JPA annotations

When hibernate executes its query it cannot find that there are some children which have a foreign key constraint with the record that is trying to remove, so it wants to execute the 'parent delete first' and then move to the 'children'.

The cause is:

> Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_PARENT_ID_PARENT: PUBLIC.CHILD FOREIGN KEY(PARENT_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.PARENT(ID) (1)"; SQL statement:
> delete from Parent where id=? [23503-200]

Database tables are created by external SQL script and hibernate is configured to avoid ddl generation. This is a requirement and it cannot be modified, so the foreign key plus the id constraint into the Child table cannot be removed.

Below you can find the Java definition of the entities, here I try to give an overview of the configuration.

**Parent entity** owns a @OneToMany with

- mappedBy = name of the field in the child
- fetch = FetchType.EAGER
- cascade = CascadeType.ALL
- orphanRemoval = true

**Child entity** owns a @ManyToOne plus @JoinColumn where:

- optional = false
- name = name of the table column

### Java code below

#### Parent.java

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
public class Parent {
    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Child> children;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Child> getChildren() {
        return children;
    }

    public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
        this.children = children;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Parent parent = (Parent) o;
        return id == parent.id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
}
```

#### Child.java

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@IdClass(ChildIdentifier.class)
public class Child {
    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,
            name ="parent_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Child child = (Child) o;
        return id == child.id &&
                Objects.equals(parent, child.parent);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, parent);
    }
}
```

#### ChildIdentifier.java

```
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

public class ChildIdentifier implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column
    private long id;
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false,
            name ="parent_id",
            referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Parent parent;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        ChildIdentifier that = (ChildIdentifier) o;
        return id == that.id &&
                Objects.equals(parent, that.parent);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, parent);
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is likely the `cascade = ALL` on `Child.parent`. `cascade = ALL` does not make sense on a `@ManyToOne`. Either remove it or downgrade it to a configuration that does not include `CascadeType.REMOVE`. BTW I didn't know you could put an association inside `IdClass`

Comment: Hi Crizzis, thanks for the feedback. I've just recognized that my "intention" is not clear after all the word in the question, so I've just modified it. I would like to keep JPA to handle the "removing" and the others action, so I am looking for a way to "fix" the deletion order. Now Hibernate is doing first parent and then children, but if I am deleting a parent I would to say to Hibernate: Hey, I am deleting a parent record, please remove the children first and then you can go for the parent

Comment: I don't think you quite understand. I'm not saying you should remove `cascade = ALL` from `Parent.children`. I'm saying you should remove `cascade = ALL` from `Child.parent`, because it makes absolutely no sense. It is basically saying: 'whenever I remove a single child, please remove the parent as well'.

Comment: You're right, I didn't understand your answer. I have modified the child scopes with your indications, but unfortunately my problem remains. Thanks for the info btw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The deletion **was not done** through the entity manager by its remove function.

The repository, which was executing the delete action, was implemented by **@Query annotation** (*example @Query("delete from parent where id = :id")*).
I have not yet fully understood the reason behind this behaviour, but JPQL was not causing the correct order deletion.

To fix the issue:

1. @Query annotation has been removed from the repository method
2. method has been renamed to deletedById for matching JPA naming convention.

This change allows Spring Data JPA to retrieve the entity by its id and then execute the entity deletion by entity manager remove function.